# How can I add a column to an existing table?

Tags: sql-server-ce

How can I alter a table in SQL Server Compact Edition (SQL CE)?

I have an existing table, and I need to add an `IDENTITY` column.

Answer (score 16):

You add a column in the same way you would add it in other versions of SQL Server:

This adds a primary key identity column called `IdColumnName` to the table `tableName`:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD COLUMN IdColumnName INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

See the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx) syntax for SQL Server compact edition.

Comment: @DannyBeckett - Thanks for the correction. Perhaps next time, just make the edit?

Answer (score 3):

Hope these examples help some one

```
ALTER TABLE [sales_order] ADD COLUMN  [price] MONEY NULL;
ALTER TABLE [order_details] ADD COLUMN  [price] MONEY NULL;
```